# How to read GCS path in local environment

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I usually do my Machine Learning work on Kaggle/Colab, however I'm trying to modularize my codes onto github. I face one big problem when I try to read files from GCS.

For example, I have `GCS_PATH = "gs://kds-432679f77c5f716920e51fb4289eb7c6d9d6"` and wish to do this:

```
TRAINING_FILENAMES = tf.io.gfile.glob(GCS_PATH + "/train*.tfrec")
```

However my vscode throws me this error `"in get_matching_files_v2 compat.as_bytes(pattern)) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: File system scheme 'gs' not implemented (file: 'gs://kds-432679f77c5f716920e51fb4289eb7c6d9d6/train*.tfrec')"`

Everything works fine on colab but fails immediately in a local environment. I am quite new to this, please advise on how to approach this problem.

Comment: You may check the [open issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38477) from GitHub related to this.

Comment: Did you check the lib versions?

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the incompatibility of version support for gcs. You may try downgrading tensorflow_datasets from 3.2.1 to 3.1.0. See a similar issue below:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38477#issuecomment-659279614
Good luck!